# Functionally program Excel code

Tags: excel, f#, add-in, excel-dna

I am rewriting my Excel VBA add-in with F# and Excel-DNA.  Formula1 below works.  It iterates through the currently selected cells and applies trim to each cells value.

Formula2 is my failed attempt at applying Functional and F# concepts.  I'm unsure how to return the range to Excel.  The formula must return a unit.

Could someone help me?

**Formula1 (Works):**

```
let Trim (rng:Range) = 
    for cell in rng.Cells do
        let cel = cell :?> Range       
        if not (cel :? ExcelEmpty) then
            cel.Formula <- cel.Formula.ToString().Trim()
```

**Formula2 (Does not work):**

```
let Trim2 (values:obj[,]) =  
    values
    |> Seq.cast<obj>
    |> Seq.map( fun x -> x.ToString().Trim() )
```

Some have asked about the reason for returning a unit or the calling function.  That is below.

```
type public MyRibbon() =
    inherit ExcelRibbon()
    override this.GetCustomUI(ribbonId) =
    "bunch of xml here"

member this.OnButtonPressed (control:IRibbonControl) =
        let app = ExcelDnaUtil.Application :?> Application
        let rng =  app.Selection :?> Range
        let rng2 =  app.Selection :?> obj
        match control.Id with
            | "AddIfError" ->  RibFuncs.RangeFuncs.AddIfError app rng
            | "Trim" ->  RibFuncs.RangeFuncs.Trim rng
                         |> ignore
            | _ ->  ()
```

Comment: These two statements contradict each other: `how to return the range to Excel` and `the formula must return a unit`

Comment: FYI, in your working code, the `formula` value you create with `let formula = ...` isn't actually used. If you add `--warnon:1182` to the `Other Flags` setting in the `Build` tab of your project properties, the F# compiler will warn you about unused values (which is extremely useful for avoiding small mistakes).

Comment: 1. John- The first formula works and returns a unit.  I call this routine from a main routine with a match statement wherein it expects a unit returned.  I know the second formula doesn't make sense, but that's what I'm asking for help with!  :)
2. Jack- good catch on that line.  I removed it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish there. Why would a formula need trimming, as opposed to e.g. a value?

The other snag is that I've been doing late binding exclusively to avoid Interop library dependencies. [Here's an implementation](http://fssnip.net/2V) of the dynamic operators for late binding.

```
let usedRange = workSheet?UsedRange
usedRange?Formula
|> box |> function
| :? (obj[,]) as a -> a
| o -> Array2D.createBased 1 1 1 1 o    // Single cell sheet
|> Array2D.iteri (fun i j formula ->
    let cell = usedRange?Cells(i, j)
    cell?Formula <- (string formula).Trim() )
```

Comment: We have systems at work that returns data with spaces on either side of the values.  I select the range, click the 'trim' macro, and it iterates through the cells trimming the unnecessary spaces.

I'll have to look at your suggestion further this weekend.  It's a bit advanced and I must decipher it...  Sorry, I'm a novice.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. You do have a perfectly fine imperative solution. If you want _more functional_, look into the functions of the Array2D module. But it will get you only so far, since I think you will need to set the property of each cell individually in any case.

Comment: @pearpies has it. You could convert the formulas to strings by omitting the `box`, changing the signature from `obj[,] -> obj[,]` to `obj[,] -> string[,]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let Trim2 (values:obj[,]) =  
    values
    |> Array2D.map(fun x-> box(x.ToString().Trim()))
```

Where are you getting the `Range` type in your "Formula 1"?